# Using Cypress, how would I write a simple test to check that a logo image exists on a page

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, cypress

specifically, I would like to test that the logo appears on the home page of the app.  I guess I am not sure what I should use to look for the image.

I tried

```
it('has a logo', function () {
    cy.visit('http://localhost:3000')
    cy.get('img').should('contains' , 'My-Logo.png')
  })
```

instead of cy.get I also tried to just use

```
cy.contains('My-Logo.png')
```

but it also fails.

I wasn't sure what element I should use or if I should be using get, but it fails.  When I look at the source code for the web page, the logo is hidden within the javascript (nodeJS, vueJS,and expressJS application) and I noticed the javascript seems to add a sequence of numbers and letters to the image when I go to the image page even though the image name in the assets folder does not have it on there.  My-Logo.d63b7f9.png.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I figured out the solution on my own.

```
cy.get('form').find('img').should('have.attr', 'src').should('include','My-Logo')
```

I inspected the element and found the `<img src...` line was embedded within a `<form>`.  I could do a `cy.get('form')` and pass, but could not do a `cy.get('img')` to pass.  So then I chained them together and it passed.  I am not sure why I cannot just simply add the second should statement, but it failed when I tried to just run:

```
cy.get('form').find('img').should('include','My-Logo')
```

I am not entirely sure why, but it needed the first "should" statement.  I got around VUE adding the sequence of numbers and letters by just asking for the name of the file without the extension.  I hope this maybe helps someone else as the documentation did not seem to cover this.

Answer (score 14):

you can use only one `should` statement like:

```
cy.get('form').find('img').should('have.attr', 'src', 'My-Logo')
```

the third arg of `should` is the value to `match` with the element attribute.

Comment: Note: this is not an exact replacement for the accepted solution. `('include', 'My-Logo')` matches on part of the text whereas using the third param expects an exact match.